# Xamarin Live Player iOS - Foundation.ModelNotImplementedException

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, foundation, xamarin-live-player

So I have downloaded Xamarin Live Player and hope to run my code on my iPhone 7. I scanned the QR code and it seems as if everything is linked through my local network.

When I go to build the app and run the debugger on my iPhone 7, I am getting the following error on my iPhone:

***Exception of type 'Foundation.ModelNotImplementedException' was thrown. (Foundation.ModelNotImplementedException)***

NOTE:
I have not change any of the code for the platform specific projects. I have only changed code in the PCL Xamarin.Forms Project.

Please help me to resolve this issue and get my app working on my iPhone for testing!

Comment: Currently, only shared solutions will deploy. Any PCL solutions will result in this error. An update should be coming soon. See the forums for more details: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/95379/xamarin-live-player-ios-foundation-modelimplementationnotfound

Comment: I dont even see xamarin live in the app store